# How do I return current index of an element in java?

Tags: java, arrays, divide-and-conquer, inversion

A pair of positions `[i, j]` with the property that `i < j` and `A[i] ≥ A[j]` (i.e. an inversion),
such that `A[i] − A[j]` is the maximum possible among all inversions in A.

```java
    class Main {
    static int[] diff(int arr[], int n){
     int index1=0;
     int index2=0;
     int maxdiff=0;
     int[] ans=new int[3];
     int i,j;
     for (i=0; i<n; ++i){
       for (j=n-1; j>i; --j){
         if(arr[i]>arr[j] && maxdiff<arr[i]-arr[j])
         maxdiff=arr[i]-arr[j];
         index1=i;
         index2=j;
         ans[0]=index1;
         ans[1]=index2; 
         ans[2]=maxdiff;

      }
     }
    return ans;

    }

     public static void main(String[] args) {
       Main max = new Main();
       int arr[]={1,20,2,6,11,16,8};
       int n=arr.length;
       int[] ans=max.diff(arr, n);
        System.out.println("i="+ans[0]);
        System.out.println("j=" + ans[1]);
        System.out.println(ans[2]);
      }
    }
```

as you can see I want to print `i=2` and `j=3` because `arr[2]-arr[3]` is the biggest inversion, I would appreciate it if someone can give me some suggestion.

Comment: When I run this code it return i=5 and j=6, I don't know what is wrong there, hope someone can help me

Comment: You mean i=1 and j=2?

Comment: You don't need divide an conquer here. I would advice to start from scratch. It can be done in one array pass. Keep track of i and i + 1. All the best

Comment: May be you want to add a set of {} for your if(arr[i]>arr[j] && maxdiff<arr[i]-arr[j])

Comment: @GuangzheLi If I understand the problem correctly, you need an algorithm which give output as Two indexes and maximum difference b/w them where `indexFirst < indexSecond and array[indexFirst] >= array[indexSecond]`

Comment: Example: {1, 21, 1, 20,  11, 6,16, 8}; Output `Largest Element Index=1
Smallest element Index=2
20`

Comment: @Harshal Parekh No. it's biggest inversion while i=1 and j=2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Main {
static int[] diff(int arr[], int n){
 int index1=0;
 int index2=0;
 int maxdiff=0;
 int[] ans=new int[3];
 int i,j;
 for (i=0; i<n-1; ++i){
//   for (j=i+1; j>i; --j){
//     if(arr[i]>arr[j] && maxdiff<Math.abs(arr[i]-arr[j]))
//     maxdiff=Math.abs(arr[i]-arr[j]);
//     index1=i;
//     index2=j;
//     ans[0]=index1;
//     ans[1]=index2; 
//     ans[2]=maxdiff;
//
//  }
     if(maxdiff<Math.abs(arr[i]-arr[i+1]))
     {
         maxdiff=Math.abs(arr[i]-arr[i+1]);
         ans[0]=i;
         ans[1]=i+1;
         ans[2]=maxdiff;
     }
 }
return ans;

}

 public static void main(String[] args) {
   Main max = new Main();
   int arr[]={1,20,2,6,11,16,8};
   int n=arr.length;
   int[] ans=max.diff(arr, n);
    System.out.println("i="+ans[0]);
    System.out.println("j=" + ans[1]);
    System.out.println(ans[2]);
  }
}
```

Comment: hi my friend, u're almost get the answer but that is a biggest inversion problem(i>j and at the same time arr[i]<arr[j]) and we're been told that we have to using divide-and-conquer.Could you please modify that code a little bit?I would appreciate for it

Comment: oooops thanks man! i ignore the brace behind the if statement, now the out put is i=1 j=2,diff=18 which is the answer.One more thing do you know how to show the output like this way([1,2] 20) , which is the best answer